# Randomly map data using useRef - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to display the data randomly for a particular id, and every time the same user loads the page gets the same data displayed first time. I am unable to randomly set data

```
const Data = () => {
 
  
  const { datas } = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();      
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!datas) {
      dispatch(fetchDatas(history));
    }
  }); 
    const adv = React.useRef(data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)]).current;
    // console.log(data + "datacoming");
    console.log(adv + "adv" );
            
 return (
     !datas?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
      <>
      <List component="nav">
        {datas.map(data => (<ListItem key={data.id} button>

          <h2>{data.code}</h2>
          <p></p>
          <p>{data.name} &nbsp;</p>

          <p>{data.intro} &nbsp;</p>   
        </ListItem>

        ) 
        )}
       </List></>
    )
  );
};

export default Data;
```

Here I want to display the list data randomly, need help. Unable to get the list data randomly. What wrong i am doing in this?

Comment: ```const adv = React.useRef(data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)]).current;```  where do you define data or mean datas ```  const { datas } = useSelector((state) => state.data); ```

Comment: datas and data is defined in store/actions as datas is a schema comprising of the fields mentioned in list. @ShambhuSahu

Comment: @Tom  can you please look into this also? I want to get random data from database and wants to show same data in same order to a particular user id. Over here I have added random selection line but i am unable to set for a particular user id. Suppose data come in order 2, 4,6, 8 so next time when user login it should be in same way instead of coming random. If possible please look.

Comment: @Aditya can you help me out with this also?

Comment: If you need I can give you the javascript code for this?
I am able to get the data from database in random order but I want that order to be saved for particular user also. So next tym when the user comes he or she can see the data in same order.