# Match fields from 2 different collection and display result based on the match mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collection one is user and one is questions. both has common field type. If user type matches with type in questions then the result will be displayed.

```
const questionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    question: { type: String },
    number: { type: Number },
    usertype: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['A' , 'B'],
    },
},{ timestamps: true });

const usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },   
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['A', 'B']
    },
}, { timestamps: true }
);
```

I want to make a query to fetch questions based on user type. If user type matches then the desired set of questions will be displayed.

This is my question.js file

```
    export const fetchQuestions = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const user = await db.findOne('USER', { _id: req.userId });
        
        const type = user.type;
        console.log(type + "user type");
        let answerdQuestions = [];
        let nextQuestions;
        let quiz;
        if (user.quiz) {
          quiz = await db.findOne('QUIZ', { user: req.userId });
          answerdQuestions = quiz.responses.map(response => response.number)
        }
        nextQuestions = getNextQuestions(answerdQuestions);
 // Here I have place query to fetch usertype questions.
        const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
        res.status(200).json({ questions, quiz: { id: quiz?._id, responded: answerdQuestions.length }, options: options });
        return answerdQuestions;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
      }
    };
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to fetch questions by usertype. So, use this query:

```
// Here I have place query to fetch usertype questions.
const type = user.type;
const questionsByUserType = await db.find('QUESTION', { usertype: type });
```

Just find all the questions from `questionsSchema` where `usertype` property matches `type` property which was derived from `usersSchema`.

Comment: According to my  question.js
 const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', { number: { $in: nextQuestions }, {usertype: type }); right? and this will give me the result? @Aditya

Comment: If you want answered questions for a particular user type, `const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', { number: { $in: nextQuestions }, {usertype: type });` will work for you

Comment: And this will fetch also questions for particular user type. Right? @Aditya

Comment: Yes @Tanyamaheshwari, understand the condtions like `and` queries. You will be getting questions which satisfy both criteria, i.e., which satisfy `number` condition and `usertype` condition both.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247434/randomly-map-data-using-useref-reactjs  can you help me out with this? please

Comment: one more thing I have to post the usertype in next collection quiz.
  responses = responses.map(response => {
      return {
        score: Number(response.value),
        number: response.number,
        category: response.category,
        description: response.description,
        question: response._id
      }

Comment: but i am not giviing the value of type in front end. so showuld I type
type: responses.type ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243379/discussion-between-aditya-and-tanya-maheshwari).

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari visit the chat link above